# Estimate solution of nonlinear differential equation by linear differential inequality

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, nonlinear-system, stability-theory

Consider the linear ordinary differential equation:
\begin{align*}
 \dot x(t) & = Ax(t), \\
 x(0) & = x_0,
\end{align*}
$t\geq 0$, $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, with $A$ is Hurwitz (i.e., all its eigenvalues have negative real part).

Then, there exists a $\Gamma > 0$ and an $\eta > 0$ such that,
\begin{align*}
 \Vert x(t) \Vert & \leq \Gamma e^{-\eta t}\Vert x_0 \Vert,\quad\forall t\geq 0,\quad \forall x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n
\end{align*}

Consider now the ODE:
\begin{align*}
 \dot y(t) & = f(y(t)) , \\
 y(0) & = y_0,
\end{align*}
$t\geq 0$, $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, with $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ a smooth function satisfying,
\begin{align*}
 f(y) \leq Ay,\quad \forall y\in\mathbb{R}^n.
\end{align*}

Is it true that there exists a $\Gamma_2 > 0$ and an $\eta_2 > 0$ such that:
\begin{align*}
 \Vert y(t) \Vert & \leq \Gamma_2 e^{-\eta_2 t}\Vert y_0 \Vert,\quad\forall t\geq 0, \quad \forall y_0\in\mathbb{R}^n\quad?
\end{align*}

---

---

My attempts:

I am trying to use the "comparison principle". This states that, if you have a scalar system $\dot u(t) = f(u(t))$, $u(0) = u_0$, and if you know that $\dot v(t) \leq f(v(t))$, $v(0) \leq u(0)$ for all $t\geq 0$, then $v(t) \leq u(t)$ for all $t\geq 0$.

Let $v := \frac{1}{2}\Vert x\Vert^2$. Then,

\begin{align*}
\dot{v} & = x^\top \dot x = x^\top A x.
\end{align*}

With, for example, $n = 2$, let,

\begin{equation}
  A = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
      a & b \\
      c & d
\end{array}
\right)
\end{equation}
Then,
\begin{align*}
\dot{v} & =x_1(ax_1 + bx_2) + x_2(cx_1 + dx_2) \leq \max\{a,d\}(x_1^2 + x_2^2) + (b + c)x_1x_2.
\end{align*}

Now, if $b = c = 0$ (which implies $a,d <0$ because $A$ is Hurwitz), then
\begin{align*}
\dot{v} &  \leq 2\max\{a,d\}v,
\end{align*}

and I can say,
\begin{align*}
v(t) &  \leq e^{(2\max\{a,d\})t}v(0)\quad \forall v(0)\in\mathbb{R}^2.
\end{align*}

I am stuck with when $b$ and $c$ are not zero... how do I deal with the cross terms?

Comment: How do you compare the vectors? Element-wise?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\dot{x}=-x$ and $\dot{y}=f(y):=-y-y^2$. Those systems satisfy your conditions. However, we have that

$$x(t)=e^{-t}x(0)$$ while

$$y(t)=\dfrac{e^{-t}y(0)}{1+y(0)(1-e^{-t})}.$$

If we now choose $y(0)<-1$, then the second system has a finite escape time. This proves that the implication you want to show is not true in general.